# Insert data in map<text,text> in cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, cql

i have a column in cassandra database as `map<text,text>`

I insert the data in this table as :

```
INSERT INTO "Table1" (col1) VALUES ({'abc':'abc','hello':'world','flag':'true'});
```

So, in my code i can get the data as :

```
{
    "abc":"abc",
    "hello":"world",
    "flag":"true"
}
```

But, now i want this like :

```
{
    "abc":"abc",
    "hello":"world",
    "flag":{
    "data":{ "hi":"cassandra"},
    "working":"no"
    }
}
```

For this, when I try the insert query, it says that it does not match the type `map<text,text>`

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here (in your second example) is that the type of `col1` is a `map<text,text>` but `flag` is a complex type and no longer matches that definition.  One way to solve this would be to create individual `TEXT` columns for each property, as well as a user defined type for `flag` and the data it contains:

```
> CREATE TYPE flagtype (data map<text,text>,working text);
> CREATE TABLE table1 (abc text,
                     hello text,
                      flag frozen<flagtype>
                     PRIMARY KEY (abc));
```

Then INSERTing the JSON text from your second example works.

```
> INSERT INTO table1 JSON '{"abc":"abc",
                          "hello":"world",
                           "flag":{"data":{"hi":"cassandra"},
                                      "working":"no"}}';

> SELECT * FROM table1;

 abc | flag                                       | hello
-----+--------------------------------------------+-------
 abc | {data: {'hi': 'cassandra'}, working: 'no'} | world

(1 rows)
```

If you are stuck on using the `map<text,text>` type, and want the value JSON sub properties to be treated a large `text` string, you could try a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.table2 (
  key1 text PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 map<text, text>);
```

And on your `INSERT`s just escape out the inner quotes:

```
> INSERT INTO table2 JSON '{"key1":"1","col1":{"abc":"abc","hello":"world"}}';
> INSERT INTO table2 JSON '{"key1":"2","col1":{"abc":"abc","hello":"world",
                  "flag":"{\"data\":{\"hi\":\"cassandra\"},\"working\":\"no\"}"}}';

> SELECT * FROm table2;

 key1 | col1
------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2 | {'abc': 'abc', 'flag': '{"data":{"hi":"cassandra"},"working":"no"}', 'hello': 'world'}
    1 |                                                       {'abc': 'abc', 'hello': 'world'}

(2 rows)
```

That's a little hacky and will probably require some additional parsing on your application side.  But it gets you around the problem of having to define each column.

Comment: I thought, I will just insert it in the form of text and in my code i will make json from the text i pass. Isn't that possible ?

Comment: Moreover, I have large number of properties (and in future, it can be extended) , so creating a table with each properties won't be feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't just mold the JSON to fit the underlying structure.  And `frozen` only means that the entire column needs to be updated all at once, not the separate properties of it (so "no" it won't help you).

Comment: you told this is one way to solve this. It is good, but the issue is i have 100s of properties and if some properties are not defined, they will be defined as null. Do you know about any other way to just enter it as a text or some other way ? it would be very difficult to define all the properties and restructure the table as the data contains in the form of map<text,text>

Comment: @demo99989 added another example.  Maybe something along those lines will help you out.

Comment: this is what I want. But this query, is giving me an issue. I update the column as : `update "Table1" set col1 = 
{'abc':'abc','hello':'world',
                  'flag':'{\'data\':{\'hi\':\'cassandra\'},\'working\':\'no\'}'} `  and I get an error saying `mismatched input 'data' expecting RULE_T_R_BRACE`

Comment: i did some coding with this, but getting an issue, could you please help me out on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150496/json-object-parse-error