# Json Object parse error

Tags: c#, json, cassandra

I am storing data in my cassandra database as string and i want to retrieve the string and convert it into json. i get an exception saying

An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' happened

is there something wrong with the data stored ? or i am doing some other thing wrong ?

My query is :

```
INSERT INTO table2(key1,col1) values ('5',{'url':'{"hello":
    {"hi":{"hey":"1","time":"5"}},
    {"reg":{"hey":"1","time":"1"}},
    {"install":{"hey":"0"}}},
    "task":"1","retry":"00",
    "max":"5","call":"140"'});


In my db when i click the map<text,text> column, it gets stored as : 

 {\"hello\":\r\n    
    {\"subscription_atrisk\":{\"hey\":\"1\",\"time\":\"100\"}},
    {\"reg\":{\"hey\":\"1\",\"time\":\"2000\"}},
\"task\":\"0\",\"retry\":\"300\",\"max\":\"5\",\"call\":\"14400\"}
```

in my c# code,  i try

```
string s = "{\"hello\":\r\n    {\"subscription_atrisk\":{\"hey\":\"1\",\"time\":\"100\"}},{\"reg\":{\"hey\":\"1\",\"time\":\"2000\"}},\"task\":\"0\",\"retry\":\"300\",\"max\":\"5\",\"call\":\"14400\"";
Jobject json = Jobject.Parse(s); //Get an Error here.
```

Could anyone please throw some light on this ?

Comment: I think your JSON is invalid because it's missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: I still get that error

Comment: Your json is invalid, don't form it manually. create an object and serialize it to get a valid json....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a closing `}`
Try:

```
string s = "{\"hello\": {\"subscription_atrisk\":{\"hey\":\"1\",\"time\":\"100\"}}, \"missing_key\": {\"reg\":{\"hey\":\"1\",\"time\":\"2000\"}},\"task\":\"0\",\"retry\":\"300\",\"max\":\"5\",\"call\":\"14400\"}";
```

Comment: yeah, slipped passed me but you're also missing a key. i put it in as "missing_key"

Comment: I am not missing any key, thats the way it is

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, an object should contain a key and either a **value** or another **object/array**.
You have syntax errors in your JSON object. First of all, always use double quotes.

Then... The `url` object  has a key `Hello` but then where you are supposed to place two more keys, you're just putting there two more objects, as if it was an array.

This could be a correct syntax:

```
{
"url": {
    "hello": {
        "hi": {
            "hey": "1",
            "time": "5"
        }
    },
    "MissingKey1":{
        "reg": {
            "hey": "1",
            "time": "1"
        }
    },
    "MissingKey2":{
        "install": {
            "hey": "0"
        }
    }
},
"task": "1",
"retry": "00",
"max": "5",
"call": "140"
}
```

Or if you really meant to have a `hello` object and an array of two more objects inside `url`:

```
{
"url": {
    "hello": {
        "hi": {
            "hey": "1",
            "time": "5"
        }
    },
    "AnArray": [{
        "reg": {
            "hey": "1",
            "time": "1"
        }
    }, {
        "install": {
            "hey": "0"
        }
    }]
},
"task": "1",
"retry": "00",
"max": "5",
"call": "140"

}
```

I suggest that before you store those JSON objects in the database, ALWAYS validate them to make sure that they're valid of syntax.

Or even better: this Newtonsoft library provides functions which serializes(creates) JSON strings from other objects. See [JsonConvert.SerializeObject Method](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)

In general it is a good idea to look around in the API documentation, it really can save you a lot of time so that you don't have to do unnecessary work.